# From where d7 render comment_form

Tags: 7, comments

Can i know from where drupal core render `comment_form` 
Actually what i mean is what is the location of file which bear `comment_form` ..In my d7 folder , i am now testing it on localhost win7.
I want to know it so that i can easily do change in comment form texts, do change in comment buttons, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rakibtg, To change the comment button text you are not supposed to change any comment module which is available in the core. Simply [Never hack Core!!!](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)

For your question, to change the comment button text,

1.You need to [write up a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/361112) with [hook_form_alter,](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
  function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] => t('Post Comments');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for altering your `comment_form`.

If you are altering the comment_form only use below mentioned code in you own custom module.

```
 function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'comment_form'){
     $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] => t('Post Comments');
   }
 }
```